# Big Issue with ExtJS Plugin FileUpload

Tags: file, plugins, extjs, upload

I have the follwing problem. I have a form that have the 'fileuploadfield', but by "default" it appears in the form screwed!. It appears with two buttons and two input fields, but one of them working and the other not working:

[image: FileUpload Issue]

As you can see in the image, the only one that works is the "grey one".

This is the function that build this item:

```
buildBrowseFoto : function() {
    return {
        xtype          : 'container',
        layout         : 'column',
        anchor         : '-10',
        defaultType    : 'container',
        defaults       : {
            width      : 300,
            labelWidth : 80,
            layout     : 'form'
        },
        items          : [  
        {
            items      :  {
                xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
                emptyText: '',
                fieldLabel: 'Foto',
                buttonText: 'Selecciona una foto...',
                name: 'foto'
            }
        }
        ]
    };
}
```

This is a function inside a class that extends FormPanel. Maybe it seems weird to you, but this the way Jay García build forms and so do I :P.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a CSS issue.  The first thing you should do is make sure you have included the `fileUploadField.css` that comes with the field.  I'll paste the contents here:

```
.x-form-file-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 22px;
}
.x-form-file-wrap .x-form-file {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 22px;
}
.x-form-file-wrap .x-form-file-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.x-form-file-wrap .x-form-file-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #777;
}
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, you must have some custom CSS or something that is messing up the form.  Try using FireBug and looking at the styles around the element, and try turning off any custom styles you might accidentally have that is overriding what should be there.

Comment: It was definitely a css issue, it's fixed now. Thanks a lot. I didn't include the css file (I didn't know it existed.)